# Conditionally set main color in Vue

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vue-component

I wrote a reusable app in Vue and I compiled it as a library. I set the global variable `$brand-color` in SCSS file which is a main color of the app (buttons, borders, font colors). I use this variable in other SCSS component files.

I've put my app to my client's website and everything is working fine. Right now I have another client who is willing to use my app. BUT... new client wants to have my app in different `$brand-color` than my old one. What would be the best way to approach this problem?

One thing which comes to my mind is to set store variable with value of `$brand-color` which depends on `location.host` and bind styles of all "branded" elements.

```
switch (location.host) {
 case 'client1.com':
    context.commit('setMainColor', '#ff0000');
    ...
 case 'client2.com':
    context.commit('setMainColor', '#16c100');
    ...
}
```

But this will be very painful. I would need to apply a lot of changes in all my components. Is there any better solution that style-binding all components?

By the way, I can't use CSS variables because code needs to be IE friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I set store value depending on my client and prepared set of SCSS classess specified for each client, i.e.:

```
.btn-client1 {
 background: red;
}

.btn-client2 {
 background: blue;
}
...
```

and I binded classes for specific elements:

```
:class="`btn-${client}`"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 files, each file definne scss variable for different customer:

**customer1_variables.scss**

```
$brand-color: green
```

**customer2_variables.scss**

```
$brand-color: red
```

And you can import it in javascript file

**main.js**

```
switch (location.host) {
 case 'client1.com':
    import './customer1_variables.scss'
    ...
 case 'client2.com':
    import './customer2_variables.scss'
    ...
}
```

Another solution is using vue-style-component. You can check [this article](https://medium.com/maestral-solutions/coloring-your-app-implementing-live-theming-with-vue-js-and-styled-components-29e428900394) for more detail

Comment: I think dynamic imports are not allowed. I've got following error while compiling: `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`

Comment: Using vue-style-component could be also be confusing, because almost all components of my app using custom styling.